# Detect when system starts a download

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

Is there a way to detect when the system starts a download and get information of it and force to download it to specific location? I googled it and results where not much helpful

Comment: Did you checked out the DownloadManager class

Comment: YEAH, BUT DOESNT LIGHT UP MUCH

Comment: Though i have never used it, but aren't there any helpful listeners?

Comment: No havent find any  through google, so thought of asking here

Answer (score 1):

Start this service class and then start your download it will print the result for status of download.

public class MyService extends Service {

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;
private static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 1000;

public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.e("Download", "onstart");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Log.d(MyService.class.toString(),
            // "tic ... "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            getDownloadData();
        }
    };
    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, SAMPLING_RATE);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void getDownloadData() {
    DownloadManager downloadMgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED
            | DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING
            | DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING
            | DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL);
    Cursor c = downloadMgr.query(query);

    if (c == null) {
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    } else {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            System.out.println("------------End--------------");
            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                getStatus(c);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void getStatus(Cursor c) {

    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    int columnReason = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);

    int reason = c.getInt(columnReason);
    int status = c.getInt(columnIndex);

    String statusText = null;
    String reasonText = null;
    switch (status) {
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
        statusText = "STATUS_FAILED";
        switch (reason) {
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME:
            reasonText = "ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND:
            reasonText = "ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS:
            reasonText = "ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR:
            reasonText = "ERROR_FILE_ERROR";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR:
            reasonText = "ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE:
            reasonText = "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS:
            reasonText = "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE:
            reasonText = "ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            reasonText = "ERROR_UNKNOWN";
            break;
        }
        break;
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
        statusText = "STATUS_PAUSED";
        switch (reason) {
        case DownloadManager.PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI:
            reasonText = "PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.PAUSED_UNKNOWN:
            reasonText = "PAUSED_UNKNOWN";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK:
            reasonText = "PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY:
            reasonText = "PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY";
            break;
        }
        break;
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
        statusText = "STATUS_PENDING";
        break;
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
        statusText = "STATUS_RUNNING";
        break;
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
        statusText = "STATUS_SUCCESSFUL";
        break;
    }

    Log.d("status", statusText + "   " + reasonText);
}
```

}